# Windows 10 On Screen Keyboard Config

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

First off, apologies if this is the wrong place to ask this question!

The issue I have is that I am trying to get the Windows 10 on-screen keyboard to show on the screen whenever the cursor is placed in a text entry field.

I have a tablet device that is running Windows 10 with no attached hardware keyboard, the software that I am hoping to interact with a WinForms application, I cannot change this application.

I have turned on the below setting in the control panel but this does not seem to help. The Windows 10 on-screen keyboard still does not show when the cursor is placed in a text box.

[image: ControlPanelKeyboardSetting]

I think the issue may be that the application is a WinForms app and/or the app is configured incorrectly.

I was wondering if you knew any workarounds for this, or know any alternative on-screen keyboards that can show whenever the cursor is placed in a text entry field.

Thanks for taking a look, I am more than willing to answer any more questions

---

**UPDATE:** The users will want to close the keyboard between data entry, so they can review what they have entered. If the keyboard is launched in the way you suggest, they will have to close it and re-launch it to achieve this use case. I was hoping for the system to be able to launch the keyboard for them after they had closed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Start** menu search by typing for **On-Screen Keyboard** (to type this, you should see on-screen keyboard when you tap into search field). Another on-screen keyboard (OSK) opens, which is intended for accessibility purposes and this one should be always visible.

---

UPDATE:
Based on your further expectations added later you can add either standard or accessibility on-screen keyboard to the taskbar so users can open it whenever they close it.

It looks that pop-up keyboard support for Windows Forms applications is inconsistent, for some types of its controls it pops up automatically but for others it does not. Therefore, nothing else than explicit displaying the keyboard (by user action) will work.

Setup of on-screen keyboards:

- standard touch on-screen keyboard: right-click the taskbar and check **Show touch keyboard button**.
- on-screen keyboard for accessibility (OSK) - launch it in way described above and pin it to the task bar.

For alternative on-screen keyboards possibly working with Windows Forms, please post question on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site, recommending software it is off-topic here on SuperUser.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the users will want to close the keyboard between data entry, so they can review what they have entered. If the keyboard is launched in the way you suggest, they will have to close it and re-launch it to achieve this use case. I was hoping for the system to be able to launch the keyboard for them after they had closed it. Thanks

Comment: @martpendle – Q&A updated.

Comment: I think you'd have to come up with the triggers to let some script know when you want, and then later, don't want that keyboard.  If you can find the triggers, you can script it to open and then later close the OSK.exe, fairly easily.

Comment: @DaaBoss – yes, they can write application monitoring the focused control and based on that, show the keyboard.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that the Winform boxes triggering the OSK is inconsistent and I would need to script the opening and closing.